# How Can I get network files in google chrome with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I am using selenium for a test in a project, but I have a problem.
I need to get network files from google chrome when I inspect element.
[image]

In this section I need this files, they are JSON files, and I need its information.

```
             //String scriptToExecute = "var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;";
        String scriptToExecute = "var network = performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;";
        java.util.List<String> s= executeJavaScript(scriptToExecute)
```

String s attribute, return me a strange List of strange objects of the network,  isn't good information for me.

This is my problem, I need JSON files, but my code returns me other things.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BrowserMobProxyServer](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/blob/master/README.md) along with selenium to get the network details of each network HAR format.

```
// Set up BrowserMobProxyServer while initiation driver
proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
proxy.start(0);

Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);

// configure it as a desired capability
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);

driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);

 proxy.newHar("google.com");

// Do all your navigation in selenium/ selenide code

driver.get("http://google.com");

// After navigation, you can find network details stored HAR
Har har = proxy.getHar();
```

If required you can store it to file before quiting the driver,

```
Har har = proxy.getHar();
File harFile = new File(sFileName);
har.writeTo(harFile);

proxy.stop();
driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a webdriver with capabilities to monitor network calls too.

```
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Driver local path);

            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
            logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);

            Map<String, Object> perfLogPrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            perfLogPrefs.put("traceCategories", "browser,devtools.timeline,devtools"); // comma-separated trace categories
            options.setExperimentalOption("perfLoggingPrefs", perfLogPrefs);
            cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

            return new ChromeDriver(cap);
        }
```

2. Now retrieve your log entries using following code.

   ```
   for (LogEntry entry : driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE)){
                   System.out.println(entry.toString());
   }
   ```

3.Result will be in following JSON format.

```
{
    "webview": <originating WebView ID>,  
    "message": { "method": "...", "params": { ... }} // DevTools message.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return JSON.stringify(network)` replace `return network`.Then `executeJavaScript(scriptToExecute)` will return *json*,but it still *String* If you don't change to json by java.You can use org.json.Just

> JSONArray netData = new JSONArray(driver.executeScript(scriptToExecute).toString());